# Limits and continuity problem

Tags: limits

What is the following limit?
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \left(\frac{x+5}{x-1}\right)^x$$
I don't know how to remove x from the power.

Comment: try logarithms.

Comment: Did you try L'Hospital's rule?

Comment: Did you try to rearrange $\left(\frac{x+5}{x-1}\right)^x$ to something of the form $\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^x$?

Comment: @GregoryGrant . I thought L hopital is applicable only for 0/0 and infinity/infinity form. Is it applicable here?

Comment: @user363973 your question is of form $\infty/\infty$.

Comment: @user363973 Yes, you first have to rewrite $a^b$ as $e^{b\ln a}$ then put it in the form $e^{(\ln a)/(1/b)}$.  Then apply L'Hospital to $(\ln a)/(1/b)$ which is now of the form $0/0$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**HINT:**

$$\left(\frac{x+5}{x-1}\right)^x=\left(\frac{x-1+6}{x-1}\right)^{x}=\left(1+\frac{6}{x-1}\right)^{x}$$.

$$\lim_{x \to \infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^{x}=e$$